# Get service via class name from iterable - injected tagged services

Tags: php, symfony, autowired, symfony-dependency-injection

I am struggling to get a specific service via class name from group of injected tagged services.

Here is an example:
I tag all the services that implement `DriverInterface` as `app.driver` and bind it to the `$drivers` variable.

In some other service I need to get all those drivers that are tagged `app.driver` and instantiate and use only few of them. But what drivers will be needed is dynamic.

services.yml

```
_defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        public: false
        bind:
            $drivers: [!tagged app.driver]

_instanceof:
        DriverInterface:
            tags: ['app.driver']
```

Some other service:

```
/**
 * @var iterable
 */
private $drivers;

/**
 * @param iterable $drivers
 */
public function __construct(iterable $drivers) 
{
    $this->drivers = $drivers;
}

public function getDriverByClassName(string $className): DriverInterface
{
    ????????
}
```

So services that implements `DriverInterface` are injected to `$this->drivers` param as iterable result. I can only `foreach` through them, but then all services will be instantiated.

Is there some other way to inject those services to get a specific service via class name from them without instantiating others?

I know there is a possibility to make those drivers public and use  container instead, but I would like to avoid injecting container into services if it's possible to do it some other way.

Comment: Make each driver a lazy service.

Comment: There is an upcoming feature that will help with this, called indexed services: https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-3-indexed-and-tagged-service-collections Unfortunately I think right now either have to create a CompilerPass if you want to solve this programmatically or add mutliple tags, e.g. based on the folder the services are stored in or by manually tagging each service.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [ServiceLocator](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/service_subscribers_locators.html) will allow accessing a service by name without instantiating the rest of them.  It does take a compiler pass but it's not too hard to setup.

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ServiceLocator;
class DriverLocator extends ServiceLocator
{
    // Leave empty
}
# Some Service
public function __construct(DriverLocator $driverLocator) 
{
    $this->driverLocator = $driverLocator;
}

public function getDriverByClassName(string $className): DriverInterface
{
    return $this->driverLocator->get($fullyQualifiedClassName);
}
```

Now comes the magic:

```
# src/Kernel.php
# Make your kernel a compiler pass
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
class Kernel extends BaseKernel implements CompilerPassInterface {
...
# Dynamically add all drivers to the locator using a compiler pass
public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $driverIds = [];
    foreach ($container->findTaggedServiceIds('app.driver') as $id => $tags) {
        $driverIds[$id] = new Reference($id);
    }
    $driverLocator = $container->getDefinition(DriverLocator::class);
    $driverLocator->setArguments([$driverIds]);
}
```

And presto.  It should work assuming you fix any syntax errors or typos I may have introduced.

And for extra credit, you can auto register your driver classes and get rid of that instanceof entry in your services file.

```
# Kernel.php
protected function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $container->registerForAutoconfiguration(DriverInterface::class)
        ->addTag('app.driver');
}
```

Answer (score 16):

You no longer (since Symfony 4) need to create a compiler pass to configure a service locator.

It's possible to do everything through configuration and let Symfony perform the "magic".

You can make do with the following additions to your configuration:

```
services:
  _instanceof:
    DriverInterface:
      tags: ['app.driver']
      lazy: true

  DriverConsumer:
    arguments:
      - !tagged_locator
        tag: 'app.driver'
```

The service that needs to access these instead of receiving an `iterable`, receives the `ServiceLocatorInterface`:

```
class DriverConsumer
{
    private $drivers;
    
    public function __construct(ServiceLocatorInterface $locator) 
    {
        $this->locator = $locator;
    }
    
    public function foo() {
        $driver = $this->locator->get(Driver::class);
        // where Driver is a concrete implementation of DriverInterface
    }
}
```

And **that's it**. You do not need anything else, it just works<sup>tm</sup>.

---

### Complete example

A full example with all the classes involved.

We have:

#### `FooInterface`:

```php
interface FooInterface
{
    public function whoAmI(): string;
}
```

#### `AbstractFoo`

To ease implementation, an abstract class which we'll extend in our concrete services:

```
abstract class AbstractFoo implements FooInterface
{
    public function whoAmI(): string {
        return get_class($this);
    }   
}
```

#### Services implementations

A couple of services that implement `FooInterface`

```
class FooOneService extends AbstractFoo { }
class FooTwoService extends AbstractFoo { }
```

#### Services' consumer

And another service that requires a service locator to use these two we just defined:

```
class Bar
{
    /**
     * @var \Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ServiceLocator
     */
    private $service_locator;

    public function __construct(ServiceLocator $service_locator) {
        $this->service_locator = $service_locator;
    }

    public function handle(): string {
        /** @var \App\Test\FooInterface $service */
        $service = $this->service_locator->get(FooOneService::class);

        return $service->whoAmI();
    }
}
```

#### Configuration

The only configuration needed would be this:

```
services:
  _instanceof:
    App\Test\FooInterface:
      tags: ['test_foo_tag']
      lazy: true
    
  App\Test\Bar:
      arguments:
        - !tagged_locator
          tag: 'test_foo_tag'
```

#### Alternative to FQCN for service names

If instead of using the class name you want to define your own service names, you can use a static method to define the service name. The configuration would change to:

```
App\Test\Bar:
        arguments:
          - !tagged_locator
            tag: 'test_foo_tag'
            default_index_method: 'fooIndex'
```

where `fooIndex` is a public static method defined on each of the services that returns a string. Caution: if you use this method, you won't be able to get the services by their class names.

Comment: This is an elegant solution, but should be noted this solution only works in Symfony >=4.

For Symfony 3 you still have to use a compiler pass

Comment: You are right. The “no longer need” implied that, but I should make it explicit. Symfony <4 installations are going el be less and less every day, but it’s worth mentioning.

Comment: I'm working on a legacy (3.4) codebase and actually trying to do just this, got halfway through your solution before I realized this was a 4+ feature. Sad face.

Answer (score 1):

Since Symfony 5.3, it's also possible to use PHP attributes to achieve this:

```php
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Attribute\AutoconfigureTag;

#[AutoconfigureTag('app.driver')]
interface DriverInterface
{
}
```

```php
namespace App;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Attribute\TaggedIterator;

class OtherService
{
    public function __construct(
        #[TaggedIterator('app.driver')]
        private iterable $drivers
    ) {
    }
}
```

[Related documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/tags.html#autoconfiguring-tags)