# In symfony, how to directly create an object as a service call？

Tags: symfony

How can I directly create an object instance in a certain way? This object is a task handler, the processor of each task may be different. Is it similar to the method of `Yii::createObject()`. I don’t want to register handlers in `service.yarml`, because there may be many handlers.

Here is what I would like to acheive:

```
$task = new Task;
// $handler = $this->container->get($task->getHandlerName()); 
$handler = createObject($task->getHandlerName());
$handler->handle($task);
// Handler

class MyHandler {
     private $manager;

      // autowiring
     public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $manager) {
            $this->manager = $manager;
     }
     public function handle() {

     }
}
```

Comment: Although it's not completely clear what you want, I suspect you want a ServiceLocator or ServiceSubscriber https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/service_subscribers_locators.html - if your handler names are all fully qualified class names, it's easier and your container line may actually work. I can't find it specifically, but you can inject all classes implementing a certain interface into a service, which would then theoretically be able to provide these as handlers via some mechanism to determine the mapping name -> class.

Comment: to reiterate ... [tagged services](https://symfony.com/doc/master/service_container/tags.html) is probably what you want, however, you have to find a way to tag all handlers, maybe via a compiler pass.

Comment: Here is an example of a [Service Locator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54946647/get-service-via-class-name-from-iterable-injected-tagged-services/54949631#54949631) implementation.  Assuming your handlers all implement a HandlerInterface then there would be no need to explicitly list handlers in services.yaml.