# Symfony Dependency Injection, doesn't autoconfigure with tagged iterator

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection

I'm using the "symfony/dependecy-injection" library (v4.4) and I think I'm missing something.

**The problem**: I'm trying to automatically add services that implement or develop a class/interface, these would have a specific tag and a service would try to retrieve all the services with this tag.

**What I've tried so far**:

```
public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
{
     $container->registerForAutoconfiguration(NamedType::class)
          ->addTag('type')
          ->setLazy(true)
     ;

     $container->autowire('type_loader', TypeLoader::class)
          ->addArgument([new TaggedIteratorArgument('type')]);
}
```

It returns an array with a "RewindableGenerator" object as a parameter to my "type_loader" service and I don't see what I can do with it.

**More info**:

1. These services are added in an extension.
2. I'm still using PHP 7.4, so I don't use any attributes.

*Because I don't want to use YAMLoader or PHPLoader, building the container is strangely complex.*

I've come across discussions on this subject (links after) but I haven't managed to solve my problem so far :

1. https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/tags.html#reference-tagged-services
2. https://riekeltbrands.medium.com/symfony-how-to-effectively-use-tagged-services-2bf6e0b11bb9

Thanks.

==> ADDED:

If it would make your life easier, perhaps you could explain to me how to do this in PHP directly without using a FileLocator, YamlFileLoader.

```
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        public: true

    Project\Framework\Endpoint\Type\:
        resource: '../../Endpoint/Type/*'
        tags: ['endpoint_type']
```

Comment: Pretty sure you need a compiler pass for this sort of thing.  Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54946647/get-service-via-class-name-from-iterable-injected-tagged-services/54949631#54949631). Though to be honest I'm not completely sure what your end game is.

Comment: @Cerad The exact context would be that I'm using the [webonyx/graphql](https://webonyx.github.io/graphql-php/schema-definition/#lazy-loading-of-types) library and I need to load my ObjectType dynamically from my container... Except that I'm not going to have fun registering each service by hand?